# XMLHttpRequest Browser Support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

Is there a reason the following snippet would not work in IE7?

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://my_site.com/';
var obj = createJsonParamsObj();
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

From the documentation it seems like the `new XMLHttpRequest()` should work, but have doubts since I can't test it (only in compatibility mode) so perhaps I better use `new ActiveXObject`.

Comment: Why do you doubt the documentation?

Comment: You're including `json2.js` in the page? As i remember, the IE 7 (and perhaps the IE 8 too) does not have the `JSON.stringify` function native, and because this we need to include `json2.js` (that can be downloaded here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to use `JSON` object and your methods.

Comment: maybe you need to clarify what is not working and do some research for   the issue

Comment: You can get a VM with IE7 from modern.ie and test with that– https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Answer (score 11):

a small search in google would provide a good answer for your basic problem

```
/*
   Provide the XMLHttpRequest constructor for Internet Explorer 5.x-6.x:
   Other browsers (including Internet Explorer 7.x-9.x) do not redefine
   XMLHttpRequest if it already exists.

   This example is based on findings at:
   http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx
*/
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined") {
  XMLHttpRequest = function () {
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
    catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
    catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (e) {}
    // Microsoft.XMLHTTP points to Msxml2.XMLHTTP and is redundant
    throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
  };
}
```

or

```
/** 
 * Gets an XMLHttpRequest. For Internet Explorer 6, attempts to use MSXML 6.0,
 * then falls back to MXSML 3.0.
 * Returns null if the object could not be created. 
 * @return {XMLHttpRequest or equivalent ActiveXObject} 
 */ 
function getXHR() { 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Chrome, Firefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  } 
  // IE6
  try { 
    // The latest stable version. It has the best security, performance, 
    // reliability, and W3C conformance. Ships with Vista, and available 
    // with other OS's via downloads and updates. 
    return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0');
  } catch (e) { 
    try { 
      // The fallback.
      return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } catch (e) { 
      alert('This browser is not AJAX enabled.'); 
      return null;
    } 
  } 
}
```

Ref : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest and http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4027629.htm

Comment: Do those `ActiveXObject` objects support `setRequestHeader`? Is it platform dependent? **EDIT**: To answer my own question here, [`setRequestHeader` was added in IE7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Thus, those `ActiveXObject`s do *not* support `setRequestHeader`, but they're not necessary in IE7 and above.

Comment: i think `XMLHTTPRequest` object was introduced in IE7, but earlier `MSXML` had support for `setRequestHeader`, check http://help.dottoro.com/ljhcrlbv.php and http://cephas.net/blog/2003/06/17/msxml2xmlhttp40/

Comment: Ah, good research! Yes, it seems that at least some forms of the ActiveX variants support `setRequestHeader`.

Comment: Google brought me here

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/ajax/xhr.js):

```
/* Microsoft failed to properly
 * implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7 (can't request local files),
 * so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
 * Additionally XMLHttpRequest can be disabled in IE7/IE8 so
 * we need a fallback.
 */
```

So better use `ActiveXObject` in IE7 like this:

```
new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

Answer (score 0):

An [example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does nearly exactly what you do in your code:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", sURL, false);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
oReq.send(sRequestBody);
```

From here, the only possible point of failure that I can even conceive of would be a bug in supporting the specific `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value for `Content-Type`, which I very seriously doubt is an extant problem.

Remember also to include a JSON library, because IE7 does not include a native `JSON` object.