# why alert says undefined for new XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html

What is the difference between

This results in undefined

```
var ipInfoRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
alert(ipInfoRequest)//results undefined
```

and this one Object Object

```
var x=new Object();
alert(x);// results Object Object
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: I get `[object XMLHttpRequest]` for the first case; what browser are you using?

Comment: If you're trying to debug code, I *highly* suggest `console.log` over `alert`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat its a embedded browser inside a application and i don't have access to console or output window.. it just loads a URL.. but it was using IE old browser which got solved after putting proper meta tag in browser IE-Edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must be doing it on older browser like **Legend IE - 7**

Here are some informative links check them out.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5.2C_and_6)

[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

[XMLHttpRequest Browser Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772568/xmlhttprequest-browser-support)

Comment: it was a embedded browser inside a application

Answer (score 0):

Opening a request is one thing.
I'm always using the following code:

```
xhr = new XHRHttpRequest(); // create a XMLHttpRequest object
xhr.open("GET", "url", true); // make a connection
xhr.send(); // send the request.
```

Hopefully you can use this information.

Greets,
Michel