# js code work in firefox not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm new in js and I would make a little program, which takes *.xml file and give response in JSON format. My code works in firefox but not in IE and chrome. I don't know why?

My html/js code:

```
<html> 
<head> </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var code = document.getElementById('text_box').value;

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                mysecondFunction(xhttp);
            }
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", code, true);
        xhttp.send();

        function mysecondFunction(xml) {
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var x = xmlDoc.documentElement.children;
        var y =' '; 

        for( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
            y += '\"'+ x[i].nodeName + '\"' + ": " + x[i].children.length + ',' + '<br>';
        }   

        if ( code.length > 0 ) {
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '{ ' + '<br>' + y + ' }';
            }
        }

        var result = document.getElementById('result');
        result.innerHTML = 'result: ' + code;
    }
</script>
<body>  
    <input type="text" name="text_box" id="text_box" placeholder="enter xml file url" />
    <input type="button" name="button_box" id="button_box" onclick="myFunction()" value="convert" />
    <div id="result">result: 
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

My example *xml file:

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>
```

Comment: Why you don't use any JS Framework like jQuery. It helps you to perform AJAX query easly mutli platform !

Comment: Yes I'll do it after, but firstly I used raw JS for practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is here:

[XMLHttpRequest Browser Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772568/xmlhttprequest-browser-support)

I would also recommend that you use an abstraction library such as jquery (http://jquery.com) to ensure cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the local filesystem to store the XML file and you are facing the issue, the solution will be to store the Javascript file, HTML file and XML files in the same folder.

If you are accessing the XML file through a server and still facing the issue, please add the error description.