# Not working in Internet explorer?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this script, which is running fine across all browsers except internet explorer. Essentially this script is refreshing the page to display the chat. Any suggestions ?

Could I get it to refresh every so often if just in internet explorer ?

```
function ajax(){

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){

document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
} 
}
req.open('GET','chat.php',true); 
req.send();

}
setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is not available in old version of IE. It is available in IE7+. If it is lower, you should use ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

Comment: make **meaningful title**, then add **what is the IE version** and add **what you trying** and **what you expect** too

Comment: Version IE ? Because i use XMLHttpRequest in IE 10/11 and it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest Browser Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772568/xmlhttprequest-browser-support)

Answer (score 0):

On old versions of IE you need window.ActiveXObject (http://blog.blackbam.at/2012/02/07/basic-ajax-skeleton-code/)

```
var XMLHTTP = null;

function AjaxRequest(compString) {

// XMLHTTP-Request Objekt erzeugen, dabei auf Browserkonformität achten
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  XMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
  try {
   XMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch(ex) {
   try {
    XMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch(ex) {
   }
  }
 }

 XMLHTTP.open("GET","test.php?compString="+compString);
 XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = MyRequestExecute;
 XMLHTTP.send(null);
}

// wird jedes mal aufgerufen, wenn der XMLHTTP-Request eine neue Stufe erreicht, bei 4 ist die Antwort des Servers eingetroffen
function MyRequestExecute() {
 // responseText als Javascript-String, responseXML als Javascript XML-DOM-Element, status Statuscode, statusText des. Beschreibung
 if(XMLHTTP.readyState == 4) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery instead of Javascript

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
       url:"chat.php",
       type:"get",
       success:function(responseText){
            document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = responseText;
        }
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

> > **This not be an answer. Adding to get idea about Support**

`XMLHttpRequest` Is not support in old IE.

[IE Supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)

[image]